# Font-Size Inconsistencies in all browsers

Tags: html, css, font-size

Does anyone know why my font-size is smaller in Firefox and so big in other browsers that it messes up all my div's?

Live site:

http://daveywhitney.com/build/cp/

css

```
width: 246px;

font-size: 12px;

margin-top: 0pt;

margin-right: 0pt;

margin-bottom: 0pt;

margin-left: 10px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using em or % instead of px for font sizes?

Here's more: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Awesome article, thanks. Very confused as to how I went so long with out running in to this problem haha : )